# I can't get Dictionary from Start function to Update function

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to have a string from .txt file that can be call using Dictionary index (lineDict["00000001"]). I created that part in Start function, it can call string from txt file (StreamReader) and assign value to Dictionary fine.
But I can't call that dictionary from Update function. I tried create a new class just for the first part, nothing change. lineDict Debugged fine, but still can't be call from different place.
(The name 'lineDict' does not exist in the current context).

Here's the code I'm stuck with.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HandleTextFIle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text m_MyText;
    public Button YesButton;
    public Button NoButton;

    public void Start()
    {
        StreamReader inp_stm = new StreamReader("Assets/Resource/Roxxy.txt");
        string line;
        Dictionary<string, string> lineDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        while ((line = inp_stm.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string indexToAdd = line.Substring(0, 8);
            //Debug.Log("index to add: " + indexToAdd);

            string lineToAdd = line.Substring(9);
            //Debug.Log("line to add: " + lineToAdd);
            lineDict.Add(indexToAdd, lineToAdd);
        }
        inp_stm.Close();
        //Debug.Log("Dict return : " + lineDict["00000000"]);
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        m_MyText.text = lineDict["00000000"];

        if (Input.GetButton("YesButton") == true)
        {
            m_MyText.text = lineDict["00000001"];
        }
        else if (Input.GetButton("NoButton") == true)
        {
            m_MyText.text = lineDict["00000002"];
        }
        
    }
}
```

the strings from txt file it calling is just

```
00000000 >AWAITING INPUT
00000001 >Do you hear me?
00000002 >INPUT RECEIVED
```

Maybe I missed some basic stuff. I dunno. Please send help or just point out the obvious stuff I missed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Like in every other language there is a scope for your variables, if you define a variable in a function it will only be visible in that function and after that function is done the variables that got created inside will get destroyed.
therefore you must declare the dictionary as global variable if you want to use it in other functions.

```
public class HandleTextFIle : MonoBehaviour
{
     public Text m_MyText;
     public Button YesButton;
     public Button NoButton;
     private Dictionary<string, string> lineDict;

     public void Start()
     {
         StreamReader inp_stm = new StreamReader("Assets/Resource/Roxxy.txt");
         string line;
         lineDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
         while ((line = inp_stm.ReadLine()) != null)
         {
             string indexToAdd = line.Substring(0, 8);
             //Debug.Log("index to add: " + indexToAdd);

             string lineToAdd = line.Substring(9);
             //Debug.Log("line to add: " + lineToAdd);
             lineDict.Add(indexToAdd, lineToAdd);
         }
         inp_stm.Close();
         //Debug.Log("Dict return : " + lineDict["00000000"]);
     }
```

Edit: that is a basic concept in most languages, if you are still a bit shaky with these things i would suggest to work through some tutorials that explain basic principle.
Here is an article about [variable scopes](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/know-scope-local-variables).